# Is it possible to define a 2D parametric curve $P(t)$ given starting point $P_0$, velocity function $v(t)$, and tangent direction function $θ(t)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, curves

Say I have three inputs:

- a starting position $P_0 = (x_0, y_0)$,
- a function for velocity over time, $v(t)$, and
- a function for the angle between the tangent direction and the $x$-axis over time, $θ(t)$.

Is it possible to define a function of 2D-position over time, $P(t)$ (or a pair of functions $P_x(t)$ and $P_y(t)$), in terms of these three inputs?

Approaching this from my limited Calc-1 perspective it seems logical to first think of moving in discrete time steps $Δt$. Start at $P_0 = (x_0, y_0)$, point in direction $θ(0)$, and move a distance of $v(0) × Δt$ to get the new position $P(Δt)$. Then point in direction $θ(Δt)$ and move a distance of $v(Δt) × Δt$ to get the next position $P(2 × Δt)$. Repeat to infinity. The points generated by this procedure are:

- $P(0 × Δt) = (x_0, y_0)$
- $P(1 × Δt) = (x_1, y_1) = (x_0 + v(0 × Δt) × Δt × \cos(θ(0 × Δt)), y_0 + v(0 × Δt) × Δt × \sin(θ(0 × Δt)))$
- $P(2 × Δt) = (x_2, y_2) = (x_1 + v(1 × Δt) × Δt × \cos(θ(1 × Δt)), y_1 + v(1 × Δt) × Δt × \sin(θ(1 × Δt)))$
- $P(3 × Δt) = (x_3, y_3) = (x_2 + v(2 × Δt) × Δt × \cos(θ(2 × Δt)), y_2 + v(2 × Δt) × Δt × \sin(θ(2 × Δt)))$
- $P(4 × Δt) = (x_4, y_4) = (x_3 + v(3 × Δt) × Δt × \cos(θ(3 × Δt)), y_3 + v(3 × Δt) × Δt × \sin(θ(3 × Δt)))$
- $...$
- $P(n × Δt) = (x_n, y_n) = (x_m + v(m × Δt) × Δt × \cos(θ(m × Δt)), y_m + v(m × Δt) × Δt × \sin(θ(m × Δt)))$

Connect each pair of sequential points with a line segment and you have an approximation of the desired curve. Let $Δt$ tend to zero, and the line-segment-approximation will tend towards a smooth curve.

However, I don't know how to go from this discrete setup to a continuous one at the limit as $Δt$ becomes the infinitesimal $dt$. How do I find the actual smooth curve in the limit? Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: $$P=P_0+\int(v\cos\theta,v\sin\theta)\,dt$$

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for a curve parametrization $\boldsymbol{P}\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, of which we know the velocity $v(t)$, and the angle of the tangent with respect to the x-axis, $\varphi(t)$.

Since you mentioned your limited Calc 1 knowledge, I assume you do not know that the tangent to a curve $\boldsymbol{P}(t) = (p_0(t),p_1(t))$ is given by it's derivative $\boldsymbol{P}'(t)$, assuming both component functions $p_0(t)$ and $p_1(t)$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

The velocity of a moving dot on a curve is thus given by $v(t) = \|\boldsymbol{P}'(t)\|_2$. Since we know both the angle and norm of $\boldsymbol{P}'(t)$, we get:
$$
\boldsymbol{P}'(t) = (p_0'(t), p_1'(t)) = ( v(t)\cos(\varphi(t)), v(t)\sin(\varphi(t)) )
$$

Integrating, if elementary possbile, gives you unique solutions for $\boldsymbol{P}(t)$, up to a constant $\boldsymbol{c}$. Using your knowledge about $\boldsymbol{P}(0)$, we can find $\boldsymbol{c} = (c_0,c_1)$.

Edit: Addendum

Assuming $v$ and $\varphi(t)$ are given by:
$$
v(t) = r_i(t) \qquad t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}]\\
\varphi(t) = s_it \qquad t\in[t_i,t_{i+1}]
$$

Where $r_i$ is polynomials of degree $k$ and $s_i\in\mathbb{R}$ is constant, and $i=0,\dots,n$. Using
[repeated integration by parts][1], we can express $p_0(t)$ as:

$$
p_0(t) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left((-1)^j\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1-j} r_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^{k-1-j}} \cos^{(j)}(s_it)\right) + (-1)^k \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k}r_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^k}\cos^{(0)}(q_it)\mathrm{d}t
$$

Where $\cos^{(j)}$ denotes the $j$-th integral of $\cos$. Replacing $\cos$ with $\sin$ yields the form for $p_1(t)$.

Edit 2:

The expression
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^k f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x^k}
$$
denotes the $k$-th derivative of $f$.

Edit 3:

Let $v(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n t^ka_k$ be a polynomial with coefficients $a_k$.
Furter let $\varphi(t) = bx^m$.

Instead of computing $p_0$ and $p_1$ seperately, we will use Euler's Identity.
Based on [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+x%5Em+*+e%5E%7Bi+*+x%5En%7D+dx) we get:
$$
\int \sum_{k=0}^n t^ka_k \exp(\mathrm{i} bt^m)\mathrm{d}t
= -\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \frac{t^{k+1}(-\mathrm{i}bt^m)^{-\frac{k+1}{m}} \Gamma(\frac{k+1}{m}, -\mathrm{i}bt^m)}{m}
$$

Where $\Gamma(s,t)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Please note that computing the integral for $\varphi(t) = \sum_{j=0}^m t^jb_j$, you cannot use this single expression.

Edit 4: We can consider one special case, namely
$\varphi'(t) = v(t)$. Then choosing a substitution $u = \varphi(t)$, we
get $\mathrm{d}u = \varphi'(t)\mathrm{d}t = v(t)\mathrm{d}t$, hence:
$$
p_0(t) = \int v(t)\cos(\varphi(t))\mathrm{d}t = \int \cos(u)\mathrm{d}u = \sin(\varphi(t)) + c\\
p_1(t) = \int v(t)\sin(\varphi(t))\mathrm{d}t = \int \sin(u)\mathrm{d}u = -\cos(\varphi(t)) + c
$$
By our knowledge of $\mathbf{P}_0 = (p_{0,0}, p_{1,0})$:
$$
p_{0,0} = \sin(\varphi(0)) + c \Leftrightarrow c = p_{0,0} - \sin(\varphi(0))\\
p_{1,0} = -\cos(\varphi(0)) + c \Leftrightarrow c = p_{1,0} +\cos(\varphi(0))
$$

Therefore the parametrization $\mathbf{P}(t)$ is given by:
$$
\mathbf{P}(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\varphi(t)) + p_{0,0} - \sin(\varphi(0))\\
-\cos(\varphi(t)) + p_{1,0} + \cos(\varphi(0))
\end{bmatrix}
$$
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Repeated_integration_by_parts

Comment: How do I integrate $P′(t)$ to get $P(t)$? You say "if elementary possbile", does that mean it isn't always possible? Per Google it looks like I might need to use "integration by parts", but I'm having trouble understanding what I'm reading.

Comment: What I mean by integrating, if elementary possible is, that not every function has an antiderivative consisting of elementary functions (polynomials, trig functions, logarithms, exponentials and the likes). For example $\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$ does not have an „elementary“ antiderivative. Sadly elementary functions are not standardized. 

You get $P(t)$ by seperately integrating $p_0(t) = \int v(t)\cos(\varphi(t))\mathrm{d}t $ and $p_1(t) = \int v(t)\sin(\varphi(t))\mathrm{d}t$

Comment: Let's assume $v(t)$ and $θ(t)$ are piecewise polynomials. How do I perform the integration $∫(v(t) \cos(θ(t))) dt$?

Comment: I'm confused by some of the notation in your update. 1: What is $q_i$? 2: How much of the whole expression is part of the Summation (is the integral included)? 3: What does it mean mathematically to have $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k-1-j} r_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}x^{k-1-j}}$ or $\frac{\mathrm{d}^{k}r_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}x^k}$?

Comment: I'm still not sure what $q_i$ is in your expression. I also just noticed that you specify $φ(t)$ as being a linear function (a constant times the parameter), but I want it to be a non-linear polynomial. Does the expression for repeated integration by parts still hold if $φ(t)$ is non-linear?

Comment: You see, using a polynomial as $\varphi$ actually produces an expression when integrating inside of $\cos$ or $\sin$, however, it is quite a hairy one. Regarding $q_i$, it is meant to be $s_i$.

Comment: Can you add the hairy expression from integrating inside the trig functions?